# htaccess, redirect to specific URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I created a new website for a club. It has a new Domain as well as different directory structure. The important pages are correctly redirected, but i want to add a catch all on the old domain to the root of the new domain. I already tried various things, currently (on the old domain and host):

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/?$ https://newdomain.com/
```

but whatever I try, this

```
olddomain.com/sub1/page1
```

is always redirecting to

```
newdomain.com/sub1/page1
```

How do I make a rule, catching all pages and redirecting to a specific URL without attaching the path to the target?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `^/?$` only matches `/` the homepage of your olddomain i.e. `http://olddomain.com/` . You need to repace your current pattern with `^/sub1/page1` so that your `http://olddomain.com/sub1/page1` can redirect to `http://newdomain.com` .

Change

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/?$ https://newdomain.com/
```

To

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/sub1/page1$ https://newdomain.com/
```

If `/page1` is a dynamic value you can replace it with  `.+` .